# jQuery multiple clicks on same div with animated click

Tags: jquery, click, hover, jquery-animate

I have a jQuery animation using hover effects, but then by click display an image and by click hide the image. I would like to be able to add a link within the div for going to a source, however, the entire div is controlled by the animate click to close image.

How can I add an href click within the same div?
Here's the test development
http://mediacrunch.com/nick/animate6.htm

**This is the setup code portion before the click events**

```
$(function(){
    $("#wrapperimghov").hide();
    $("#wrapperimghov").fadeIn(6000);
    $("img", this).hide();
    $("png", this).show();
    $(".divhov").hover(animated1, animated2);       
    $(".divhov") .toggle(animated3, animated4);

}
);

function animated1() {

    $( this ).hoverFlow( 'mouseenter', { width: "30px", height:"420px" }, { queue: false, duration: 1000  });

}
function animated2() {

    $( this ).delay(1200) .hoverFlow( 'mouseleave', { width: "10px" , height:"320px" }, { queue: false, duration: 1800});
$("img", this).fadeOut(1800), fadeoutcallback();

}
```

**Now is the click events**

```
    function animated3() {
    $( this ).animate( { width: "420px", height:"420px" }, { queue: false, duration: 800 });
    $("img", this).fadeIn("slow"), fadeoutcallback();
}
function animated4() {
    $( this ).animate( { width: "10px" , height:"320px" }, { queue: false, duration: 800 });
    $("img", this).fadeOut("slow"), fadeoutcallback();

}

function fadeoutcallback(){
$("img", this).hide();
}
```

So, I am assuming I need another div somehow nested outside of the clickable div, or, this is the million dollar question, can I have another mouse pointer indicating a different state showing the link to href?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ave3q/

stop the click event with `ev.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Thanks, regrettably I only now uploaded my code which shows not one but two click events, one to open the image and one to close it. So, it's the second click which interferes.

So, I am looking for a different link mouse hover look for another href link, or I'm assuming I need to wrap an overall div and have within that, one div for the image and one for the href link.

What do you think?